# Lotus Notes Document Types

Tags: .net, api, lotus-notes

Which **Lotus Notes Types Document Types** can be distinguished, respectively which values for a "Form Item" of a Document in an **NSF file** are possible ("Memo", "Appointment", "Task",...)? Unfortunately I cannot find a comprehensive list in the Notes (Com) API documentation.

Answer (score 3):

There are no set "types" of Lotus Notes documents.  There are just Notes documents.  They are unstructured containers of data, specifically NotesItems.  One of the NotesItems most documents contain is called the Form NotesItem.  That item ties the document to one of the forms in the NSF, which will be used to create and edit those documents.

You can change the Form item in a document programmatically, and Notes will try to open it using that different form, for example.  You can remove the form item completely from a document and it is still a document (although you can't of course edit it via the UI then, but you get my point)

NSF Databases contain a number of forms, that act most like the different data types for the application, so look at what forms are available to get your answer.  Another thing you can do is create a view that categories all documents by form, and you'll get a sense of what documents are in the database and how many for each form.

Answer (score 2):

Notes database is a generic document data base. A document is an arbitrary set of fields. By best practice, each document should have a field named "Form". That is the "document type". But it is all best practice, so you won't find info in the API doc. The meaning of "Memo", "Appointment", "DeliveryReport", etc is defined by the application. Some applications or templates (.ntf) contains sometimes doc. about their values used in the "Form" field.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has already been said by Ken Pespisa and PeterMmm, though, there are a number of forms that are central to some Notes operations, particularly messaging and calendaring and scheduling, all of which are parts of the Notes Mail database, such as the Memo, Appointment, Task and _Special_Link Message forms. You can find a list of all of these common forms by opening a mail database (or the mail template) in Designer: they will be the forms that are not hidden (that is, their names are not parenthesized). Many of these are available everywhere in Notes from the Create menu, regardless of which database you are working in at the time.

And note that there won't necessarily be a corresponding form design element for every Form field value you find in Notes. The Form item's position in a data note's storage is privileged (like the UNID and the NoteID), so it is very fast to search on the Form item value as compared to other field values. That means that in "headless" applications (Notes databases that rely on other apps to provide the UI, or perhaps that have no UI) the Form value may just be a way to select documents into views and nothing more.

Welcome to the wonderful world of NoSQL, Document Store Edition. Notes was here first, and CouchDB, which is similarly arranged, was developed by the same guy who wrote the current version of the Notes Formula Language engine. It may take some getting used to having no adults around to tell you what to do (no table constraints, etc.) but it means you can build some pretty cool stuff.